# ASP.NET Core IIS Project not running or producing any logs

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, .net-core

**I have:**

- an EC2 instance running Windows Server 2016,
- the .NET Web Host Bundle installed (including the .NET Core 2 SDK),
- the AspNetCoreModule installed,
- a site in IIS10 and an app pool with no managed code,
- the following `BuildWebHost`:

  ```
  public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
      WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
          .UseKestrel()
          .UseIISIntegration()
          .UseStartup<Startup>()
          .Build();
  ```
- this web.config for ASP.NET Core 2 MVC in the sites root folder:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <configuration>
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\ProjectOutput.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" />
    </system.webServer>
  </configuration>
  ```

**What works:**

- placing an `index.html` with any content in the root folder of the site.

  - the content of the file is served properly when I goto the site from an external network or computer.

**What doesn't work:**

- placing my published ASP.NET Core MVC site in the root folder of the site, serves a 500 Internal Server Error

  - published using `dotnet publish`
- additionally, nothing is getting logged either.

What could I be missing that would cause my project to not start, without any logging?

Comment: Still no progress on this issue. Scouring the internet for answers has revealed nothing for me.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. Although I'm not even getting a 500. Have you tried checking the eventviewer?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. For some reason my asp.net core application is not working on IIS. Only get the message: An error occurred while starting the application.

No logging, or eventviewer.

Answer (score 1):

I know I commented an houre ago, but reading this issue I thought I had the same problem.
What helped for me was removing the following from the Startup.cs in the configureServices method:

```
Services.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
```

I noticed that when publishing the application, the application in IIS was still asking for a tempkey.rsa. That's weird because this one is not published with it. So after removing the certain line of code it's all working.

Also a great tip to remember, if you can't figure out the error: go to the folder of your application. Open command. And enter: `dotnet .\NAMEOFSTARTING.DLL`

This way you start your website from the command, and see possible errors.